# Powershell - get all default values for a document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell, default-value

I am attempting to write a powershell script that will iterate through all document libraries and provide me with the default values for specific columns.

I am successfully iteration through the sites, and their respective lists, but for a column named "NH Department" I would like to know if a default value has been set or not, and if so, what the default value is.  I have tried the following with no success (partial, applicable code below):

```
foreach ($list in $subWeb.Lists)
{
  $listname = $list.Title

  $FieldName = $list.Fields["NH Department"]
  Write-Output $("NH Department: " + $FieldName.value)

}
```

I guess I don't know how to query the VALUE of the field I am targeting.  I am not even confident I am finding the field properly above (probably not).

The fields in question are Managed Metadata fields that are part of a site column, which in turn is part of a content type applied to the document library.

EDIT:  Complete code

```
$webApplicationURL = "http://www.site.com/"
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $webApplicationURL

if($webApp -ne $null)
{
  $webAppName = $webApp.name
  Write-Output "Web Application : $webAppName"

  foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
    { 
     if($siteColl -ne $null)
      {
        $siteCollName = $siteColl.Url
         Write-Output "Site Collection : $siteCollName"

         foreach($subWeb in $siteColl.AllWebs)
          {
            if($subWeb -ne $null)
              {
              $subWebName = $subWeb.Title
              Write-Output "Site : $subWebName"

              foreach ($list in $subWeb.Lists)
              {
                $listname = $list.Title
                if($lastlistname -ne $listname){Write-Output "List: $listname"}

                $FieldName = $list.Fields["NH Department"]
                Write-Output $("NH Department: " + $FieldName.DefaultValue)

              }
                 $subWeb.Dispose()
              }
           else
              {
                Echo $subWeb "does not exist"
              }
          }
            $siteColl.Dispose()
       }
     else
         {
            Echo $siteColl "does not exist"
         }
     }
} else
     {       Echo $webApplicationURL "does not exist, check the WebApplication name"
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is property called DefaultValue.

```
$FieldName = $list.Fields["NH Department"]
Write-Output $("NH Department - Default Value " + $FieldName.DefaultValue)
```

Comment: yes, tried that as well... but it is not returning anything at all.  Is it because it is a managed metadata term?
    
     foreach ($list in $subWeb.Lists)
     {
     $listname = $list.Title
     $FieldName = $list.Fields["NH Department"]
     Write-Output $("NH Department: " + $FieldName.DefaultValue)
     }

Comment: Does it have a default value? If it has a default value, it will return it. If not, it won't return anything--Regardless of if it's a managed metadata property.

Comment: yes, for example, I navigated to a site's document library and say (via the GUI) that it has a default value.  finding it in the output of the script though, it shows nothing
    
    `Site : Board & Administrative Services

    List: Board & Admin Services Documents

    NH Department:`

I updated my OP with the complete code.

Comment: i figured it out.  not sure why my code wasn't working, but made a simpler script which worked.  thank you!